# Is there any way in PHP to store $variable of $variable in session

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I created a web-page,where you can search **plant's scientific name**. Type plant name in **search_text** it will give you results in **search_result(live search like google and facebook search bar)** . Ex: when you will type C in search input, in search result you will get C related search. Like C typed in search input, in search result it will start showing Cucumber(Cucumis sativus), Capsicum(Capsicum annuum), etc.

Now I want when you will click on Cucumber(Cucumis sativus) in search result, it have to direct to **home.php/Cucumber** . Or when user click on Capsicum(Capsicum annuum), it have to direct on **home.php/Capsicum** .

And on **home.php** in **body tag** I want to display plant name with their scientific name. And in **para tag** information related to plant search result.

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Search</title>
      <style type="text/javascript" 
         src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </style>
      <style type="text/javascript">
      function searchq() {
      var searchTxt = $("input[name='search']").val();
      $.get("search.php", {searchVal: searchTxt}, function(output) {
      $("#output").html(output);
      });
      }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="index.php" method="post">
         <input type="text"  name="search" id="myInput1" autocomplete="off" 
            placeholder="Search username..." onkeydown="searchq(); " />
         <input type="submit" value=">>"/>
      </form>
      <br> 
      <div id="output"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**search.php**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root');
mysqli_select_db($con, 'plant');
$output = '';
if (isset($_GET['searchVal'])) {
    $searchq = $_GET['searchVal'];
    $sql = "select * from type where plant like '%$searchq%'";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("could not search");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($count == 0) {
        $output = 'There is no serach result';
    } else {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $plantname = $row['plant'];
            $sciencename = $row['species'];
            $id = $row['id'];
            $output .= '<div>' . $plantname . ' ' . $sciencename . '</div>';
        }
    }
}
echo '<a herf="home.php/">' . $output . '</a></div>';
?>
```

Comment: Your question title talks about sessions, but I don’t see you using them anywhere here. And I don’t see how using them would make sense either, since you apparently want to get information that was send with the _current_ request. If your _actual_ question is how to get the value `Cucumber`, when `home.php/Cucumber` was requested, the answer is called PATH_INFO.

Comment: I'm voting to close since it's unclear what you are asking, no effort to format code readable.

Comment: And how to print Cucumber and their scientific on home.php

Comment: OT: widely open to sql injection : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: I have rejected the edit because it does harm to the snipet by changing tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this

Passing the name of the plant as a GET param is not an option?

You could do

```
echo "<a href='home.php?plantname={$plantname}' target='_blank'>{$output}</a></div>";
```

As the response of your server, that would create the link and in home.php you retrieve the plant name with $_GET['plantname'].

in home.php you do

```
if(isset($_GET['plantname'])){
    echo $_GET['plantname'];
}
```

Comment: Is it throwing an exception or something? What PHP version are you running?

Comment: Leave it I deleted my all project.

Comment: Would you like to remove your question?

Answer (score 0):

Please correct this line in index.php

```
<style type="text/javascript">
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: It was my mistake sorry for that.